# Vertical More dotted options

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a right border and make it clickable on an html page. It should look similar to the screenshot below. How can I achieve it in simple HTML,CSS or bootstrap without any plugin?

I tried border-right to a div, which makes other links inside the div clickable.

[image]

I have tried pseudo as well. Also the following:(I need it for dotted-border)

```html
<div class="dotted-border">

     <!--Assigned Room-->
     <div
      ng-if="selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber !== null && selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber !== undefined">

      <!--Shared room-->
      <span ng-if="quickRoomChangeVm.isSharedReservation"> <img
       title="Shared Room Reservation" class="alignWithText"
       src="/ui/assets/images/QuickCheckIn/shared_white.png" />&nbsp;
      </span> <span
       ng-attr-title="Room {{selectedRoom.id + 1}}: {{selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber}}">
       <span class="roomCount"> Room {{selectedRoom.id +1}}: </span> <span>
        {{selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber}} </span>
      </span>

      <!--Lockout-->
      <span ng-if="selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.lockAssgn"> <img
       src="/ui/assets/images/QuickCheckIn/lock_white.png"
       title="Room cannot be changed">
      </span>

     </div>


     <!--Unassigned room-->
     <div
      ng-if="selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber === null || selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber === undefined">
      <!--Shared room-->
      <span ng-if="quickRoomChangeVm.isSharedReservation"> <img
       title="Shared Room Reservation" class="alignWithText"
       src="/ui/assets/images/QuickCheckIn/shared_white.png" />
      </span>

      <!--Not Assigned-->
      <span ng-attr-title="Room {{selectedRoom.id + 1 }}: Not Assigned">
       <span class="roomCount"> Room {{selectedRoom.id + 1}}: </span> <span>
        Not Assigned </span>
      </span>
     </div>

     <!--Room Status-->
     <div
      ng-if="selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber !== null && selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.roomNumber !== undefined">
      <span
       ng-attr-title="{{selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.occupancyStatus | capitalize}}, {{selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.housekeepingStatus | capitalize}}">
       <span> {{selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.occupancyStatus |
        capitalize}}, </span> <span>
        {{selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.housekeepingStatus |
        capitalize}} </span>
      </span>
     </div>

     <!--View Full Details Link to open Pop-up-->
     <div ng-if="selectedRoom.selected">
      <span
       ng-click="openFullRoomDetailsPopup(selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail, selectedRoom.assignedRoomDetail.connectingRoomDetail)"
       title="View Full Details"> <u>View Full Details</u>
      </span>
     </div>
                    
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try working with the element, and it's `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having this text:

```
<span class="vertical-text">...</span>
```

Simple css approach:

```
.vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    float: right;
}
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7bm9L1o/

You can also use an image an rotate it

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  outline: none;
}
.dots,
.dots:before,
.dots:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.dots:before,
.dots:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dots:before {
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.dots:after {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-icon">
  <span class="dots"></span>
</button>
```